# RAID1 w/Intel RST -- can I replace failed drive with bigger drive?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, raid-1, intel-rst

### The Setup

- I have 2 x 1TB drives in a RAID1 configuration.
- One of the hard drives has failed and so my RAID situation is degraded.
- All data is backed up via Backblaze as well so I'm not worried about losing it.

### The Goal

- I'd like to upgrade while I'm replacing, to buy a 2 TB or 3TB drive, hook that up to the Raid 1, and then replace the working 1 TB drive with another 2 TB or 3TB drive when it eventually breaks.

### The Question

Is this an alright idea (assuming I don't plan to hit the 1 TB threshold anytime soon), and does Intel RST allow for this? I'd like to know before I go spend my money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can replace the drive with a larger one, but you can't use the higher capacity until you replace the other drive as well. I'd recommend doing the upgrade all at once.

- Break the RAID (so that the drive is a single disk)
- Copy the data to the new drive (Ghost, Acronis Disk Image etc.)
- Expand the partition
- Replace the other drive
- Rebuild the RAID1 from the copied data

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for. Just to clarify: are you recommending cloning the drive so that the raid doesn't tax itself trying to synchronize the drives?

Comment: @goober The main point of cloning instead of rebuilding the RAID is the speed: usually RAID rebuilding has a lower priority, so the copying is done slower. When copying with an application it's done in the foreground with high priority, so the process goes faster.